# Exception org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.lg.log4j2 when attempting to add log4j 2 as module in jBoss eap 7

Tags: configuration, ejb, log4j2, jboss7.x

I am using log4j 2.16 for my EJBs. Im meaning to add the log4j-core (and log4j-api if necessarily ) as module in jBoss eap 7 but I keep getting the ModuleNotFoundException exception.

here is my configurations :

**src/main/ressource/META-INF/jboss-deployement-structure.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.lg.log4j2"/>
        </dependencies>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**jboss-eap-7.0 - 22\modules\system\layers\base\org\lg\main**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.lg.log4j2">
    <resources> 
         <resource-root path="log4j-api.jar"/>
         <resource-root path="log4j-core.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

*the two jar exist in the current folder.*

**EJBXX.jar.failed**

```
WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.EJBXX.jar:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.lg.log4j2:main\"}}"
```

I am not sure about my solution so please correct me if there is another way to achieve it.

N.B: I spot this error in my jBoss console :

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module is in the wrong directory. It needs to be in `org/lg/log4j2/main`. You’re also likely missing some module dependencies too.